# Most efficient way to filter rows in a spark dataframe based on max value in a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe named flightData2015 in the following format:

```
+--------------------------+---------------------+-------+
| Destination_country_name | Origin_country_name | count |
+--------------------------+---------------------+-------+
| United States            | Romania             |    15 |
| United States            | Croatia             |     1 |
| United States            | Ireland             |    15 |
| Egypt                    | United States       |    10 |
+--------------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

I want to get all the rows that have the max count. So in the above example I will get the result:

```
+--------------------------+---------------------+-------+
| Destination_country_name | Origin_country_name | count |
+--------------------------+---------------------+-------+
| United States            | Romania             |    15 |
| United States            | Ireland             |    15 |
+--------------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

I can do this via SparkSQL as follows:

```
spark.sql("select * from flight_data_2015 where count = (select max(count) from flight_data_2015)")
```

However, as expected when I check the execution plan I find that there are multiple passes over the dataset.

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME#10, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME#11, count#12]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(count#12) && (count#12 = Subquery subquery209))
   :  +- Subquery subquery209
   :     +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[max(count#12)])
   :        +- Exchange SinglePartition
   :           +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_max(count#12)])
   :              +- *(1) FileScan csv [count#12] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Users/utk/Documents/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/flight-data/csv/2..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<count:int>
   +- *(1) FileScan csv [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME#10,ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME#11,count#12] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Users/utk/Documents/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/flight-data/csv/2..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(count)], ReadSchema: struct<DEST_COUNTRY_NAME:string,ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME:string,count:int>
         +- Subquery subquery209
            +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[max(count#12)])
               +- Exchange SinglePartition
                  +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_max(count#12)])
                     +- *(1) FileScan csv [count#12] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Users/utk/Documents/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/flight-data/csv/2..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<count:int>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do it in one pass. If not, what is the most optimal way to do this with and without SparkSQL.

Also please keep in mind that the dataframe actually has more than 2 Billion rows, so shifting everything to one partition will not be possible.

Comment: How could you do it in 1 pass?

Comment: If you think about it, it is quite easy to optimize this by an Optimizer.

Comment: Create a Dataframe by reading the input then perform `df.agg(max($"count"))`

Comment: @thebluephantom As you iterate through partition of the df, keep track of the current max and maintain a list of all rows encountered so far having that max. As soon as you encounter a new max, empty the list, and start adding rows that have this new max. Since you just encountered this new max, there is no chance of having missed a previous row. In this way you can determine the max in a single partition and rows corresponding to it. Then use the same algo as df.agg(max($"count")) to determine global max across partitions and keep or discard the lists accordingly.

Comment: @thebluephantom cont.. trouble is I don't know how to do this via the standard spark API

Comment: @shriyog I am aware of the df.agg() function. You would need to get the max from it and then use it in df.filter() I am curious if it's the most optimal way to filter based on max even in two passes?

Comment: There is no issue to do this the way you showed. You mean dsl? So what? Why make life complicated?